# Template.myTemplate.rendered in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, render

What is the use of Template.myTemplate.rendered in Meteor?. I had studied the document but i didn't understand the exact functionality.The document says `Provide a callback when an instance of a template is rendered`. What is the meaning of instance of a template is rendered.Can you please suggest me with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the callback is fired, an instance of the template has been rendered (added to the document). It can be useful if you for example want to manipulate the elements in the template through the use of a JavaScript library, for example CodeMirror, as I used in one of my projects. For example:

```html
<template name="test">
    <textarea></textarea>
</template>
```

```js
Template.test.rendered = function(){
    // Make the textarea highlight the code (kind of).
    var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this.find('textarea'))
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the rendered function when executes?.@Peppe L-G

Comment: @Venkat It executes immediately after the template HTML is inserted into the DOM (thus, it can safely be manipulated with like jQuery).

Comment: I try to execute the above same scenario.I test with a console.log but never goes to render method.So what is use of the above rendered method.@ Brad M

Comment: @Venkat Somehow you must tell Meteor to insert the template into the DOM, for example by putting `<body>{{> test}}</body>` in a HTML-file.